# Why didn't Voldemort create a Horcrux with a Gryffindor heirloom?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

Voldemort was said to be very interested in the four founders of Hogwarts. He created a Horcrux from the Ravenclaw diadem, the Hufflepuff cup, and the Slytherin locket. Did he try to find a Gryffindor relic to complete the set, or did he not bother?

I can't see him giving up on such a task, but maybe there was insufficient time.

Gryffindor's sword was hiding 'inside' the Sorting Hat, but a famous family usually has some other heirlooms too.

If there are no canon answers I'd be interested in your own speculation!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From Dumbledore himself in HBP, while discussing Voldemort's horcruxes with Harry:

> "I am confident, however, that the **only known relic** of Gryffindor remains safe."
>
> <sub><sup>HBP, Chapter 23, p505, Scholastic Edition. Emphasis added</sup></sub>

So, I believe we can take this as confirmation that no other family has another heirloom. Else, Dumbledore and other magical historians (like Bagshot) would've known about it.

And, as we know, only Gryffindors can take the sword from the Sorting Hat. Voldemort, as a Slytherin, wouldn't be able to even if he wanted; he's really better off giving up since he is unable to acquire it by himself. Though he may be able to trick a Gryffindor into getting it from the Hat for him, remember that Voldemort likes to operate alone, especially when it comes to his horcruxes. So I don't think that plan would appeal to him.

(It's worth noting too that the Sorting Hat is a relic of Gryffindor's. I don't know if it can be turned to a Horcrux tho, given its current enchantment.)

Comment: One of his followers did have access to the sword; Bellatrix had it (or at least thought she did).

Comment: @Richard, yep but that was only in DH, way after he has begun with his horcrux scheme; at the time, he's got more pressing issues than horcruxes. And he only realized that his horcruxes were in trouble _after_ Harry has broken in the Lestrange vault; even if the vault held the true sword, and he decided to turn it to a horcrux, Harry would've already stolen it. Lastly, thanks for the edit tip. That's what I wanted indeed.

Comment: Regardless of whether you *can* do it, turning a sentient object which can blab on you and which lives in the Hogwarts headmaster’s office seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Snape did have the sword when he took it to the Forrest of Dean, and he is not a Gryffindor.

Comment: It would be rather disadvantageous to Voldemort if his horcrux vanished into the hands of a Gryffindor.

Comment: @sassie IIRC, Dumbledore (a Gryffindor) took it from the hat to destroy the ring horcrux and it was on display at the Headmaster's office since then. Snape did not really get it _from the hat_.

Comment: So the famous Griffindor family did not even hand down a pair of cufflinks through the generations? I suppose Voldemort would only be interested in 'the' relic, not just any heirloom.

Comment: I think that was the point of Voldemort coming back to work at hogwarts, to find my relics, i believe dumbledore says as much after showing Harry that memory. He at that point already had 3 relics so he was attemptnig to find a gryffindor relic.

Comment: Voldemort would need two things to make his horcrux: the sword and a victim. Befriending a member of Gryffindor sounds like something he could have easily done considering how charismatic Voldemort was. He'd just need to find someone curious enough to be willing to investigate and seek out the sword. Once the sword is found, well, he'll have the second component he needs right there already. I suspect, however, that acquiring/keeping the sword is more difficult than just "you have to be from Gryffindor."

Comment: "remember that Voldemort likes to operate alone, especially when it comes to his horcruxes" - well, he used Kreacher to create a horcrux in Slytherin's Locket. Also, creating a horcrux oftenly requires a victim.

Answer (score 11):

I think the answer is simply that it would be *impossible to protect*, seeing as ANY Griffindor could pull the sword out of the hat. No matter what protections he put on it, any one of his enemies who was in Griffindor would have easy access. It would never be safe.

Comment: Not to mention that the sword only takes what makes it stronger.  I doubt that it would consider being a Horcrux stronger (though this is obviously debatable).

Answer (score 8):

Even though he probably didn't realize it, he did have a Horcrux in each house.

- The Locket/Slytherin.
- The Cup/Hufflepuff.
- The Diadem/Ravenclaw.
- *Harry Potter*/Gryffindor.

Comment: Harry is not a Horcrux, nor is he a "Gryffindor heirloom"

Comment: @Skooba Harry is indeed a Horcrux made by accident on the 31st of October 1981

Answer (score 0):

Gryffindor is his enemy, so it's probably too risky to put a part of his soul in his enemy's hands.

If he obtained it and hid it, the Gryffindors will go searching for it.

That's my speculation.

Comment: I'm not convinced there would have been a mass stampede of Gryffindors clambering to recover the Sword of Gryffindor from Voldemort, were he to have taken it. There is no canon evidence that the Hufflepuffs, Slytherins, or Ravenclaws went searching for their respective founders' heirloom after each heirloom went missing. I mean, that would be very noble, and I think of all the houses, were that to happen, Gryffindor would lead the charge, but I personally (and YMMV, of course) don't see this happening on a house-wide scale. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess: an awful lot of people (not just Ravenclaws) went looking for the diadem, as I recall.  Was it commonly known that the other heirlooms were missing?

Answer (score -2):

The sword only takes in that which makes it stronger. Voldemort's repulsive soul is not something the enchantment would accept as making it more powerful.

And even if this weren't the case, and Dark Lord Soul is something to be acquired for strength, it appears as though Dumbledore himself was personally protecting the sword, since he alone admits to having created the enchantment that prevents the sword from presenting itself to ill-deserving individuals.

I daresay Voldemort was apprehensive to touch or even be near the actual sword himself, as he did not inspect the fake in the Lestange Vault and he did not show any desire to pick it up after killing Griphook. Perhaps he fears anything enchanted by Dumbledore?

Comment: -1. I very much doubt the sword was enchanted by Dumbledore.